# Python program that is given a line read from a text file and displays the one number found

Tags: python

```
def extractTemp():
    inputFile = open('P2text.txt','r+')

    line = inputFile.readline()

    for chr in line:
        if chr.isdigit():
            print(chr)
            inputFile.close()

extractTemp()
```

The text file has the number `95` in it, but it prints as:

```
9 
5
```

I'm guessing because it is iterating over each character and makes `95` two separate characters.

So my question is, how do I combine them. Or, what can I do to make this program run better?

Bc a big hole in finding the solution to combining the numbers is, what happens when there are two separate numbers like 95 and 90.

Then that would become 9590 if I linked everything together. So what can I do to make this work?

Basically, if given a sentence in a text file a sentence that says "I have the number 95 and 90" I want to be able to print just those two integers and ignore the rest. But the way I'm doing it, it would print 9,5,9,0 on separate lines.

So I'm just wondering how to print them together as in 95 is 95 and not 9,5 and 90 is 90 not 9,0. So the end result I want from reading that sentence is: >> 95 90 after running the program Or, if I can only get a sentence that says "I have the number 95" and for it to print: >> 95 I'd be happy with that too

Comment: You're right that you're getting `'9'` `'5'` on two separate lines as your output because you're iterating by character. I'm not sure what kind of input you're expecting that's supposed to be two separate numbers? like `'95 90'` or like `95\n90`?

Comment: Sorry if that part confuses you. I didn't explain it very well. Basically, if given a sentence in a text file a sentence that says "I have the number 95 and 90" I want to be able to print just those two integers and ignore the rest. But the way I'm doing it, it would print

Comment: 9,5,9,0 on separate lines. So I'm just wondering how to print them together as in 95 is 95 and not 9,5 and 90 is 90 not 9,0

Comment: So the end result I want from reading that sentence is:
>> 95 90 
after running the program 
Or, if I can only get a sentence that says "I have the number 95" and for it to print: 
>> 95
I'd be happy with that too.

Comment: You should edit that into the question. I'll answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting input like:

> Here is 95 and there is 90

and want output of:

```
95
90
```

You should probably use regular expressions.

```
import re

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    text = inf.read()  # generally bad practice, but...

numbers = re.findall(r"\d+", text)  # ['95', '90']
for number in numbers:
    print(number)
```

But since you seem to be a new programmer, I wouldn't expect you to jump into the wild world of regular expressions just yet. They're massively powerful, but ultimately unnecessary here. You could instead do:

```
with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    text = inf.read()

chars = [ch for ch in text if ch.isspace() or ch.isdigit()]
# [' ', ' ', '9', '5', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', '0']
# every space and every digit

chars = ''.join(chars)
# "  95    90"
# join every element with the empty string

numbers = chars.strip().split()
# ['95', '90']
# strip off leading and trailing whitespace, then split on groups of whitespace

for number in numbers:
    print(number)  # as before
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for num_str in line.split():
    try:
        print int(num_str)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use split() function as shown below:

```
inputFile=open('test.txt','r')
line=inputFile.readline().split()
for num in line:
    try:
        print int(num)
    except:
        pass
inputFile.close()
```

and the result will be:

```
90 95
```

Comment: When trying this, it just splits the whole sentence into separate lines. So if it was "This number is 95" It prints 
>>This 
>>number
>>is
>>95

Comment: @Trey I misunderstood you. Then you can use the try/except sentence. I have edited the answer, although it seems that somebody else has already solved your problem...

Answer (score -1):

You can make a list of the digits in the line and print them.

```
def extract_temp(n):
    temp=[]
    line=n.readline()
    for ch in line:
        if ch.isdigit():
            temp.append(ch)
    print("".join(temp))
```